# как передать в intent словарь(map)

Tags: android, kotlin, activity, android-intent, serializable

из начально словарь mutable но на попытку его передать ас жалуется, и я переписал передачу таким образом:

```
val maP = linkedMapOf<Any,Any>()
            maP.putAll(mapc)
            val maP2 = linkedMapOf<Any,Any>()
            maP2.putAll(e)
            int.putExtra("currencys", maP)
            int.putExtra("icons",maP2)
            int.putExtra("button", "button1")
            startActivity(int)
```

но проблема в том что на попытку типизировать полученный словарь приложение крашится типизировать я его пытаюсь так:

```
var currencys = intent.extras?.getSerializable("currencys")
var icons = intent.extras?.getSerializable("icons")
var button = intent.extras?.getString("button") 
adapter.update(currencys as LinkedHashMap<Any,Any>, icons as LinkedHashMap<Any,Any>)
```

Comment: Чтобы сериализовать словарь, ключ и значение должны быть сериализуемы. Попробуйте явно указать типы...